# Defer loading and parsing of PrimeFaces JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, deferred-loading

While analyzing the performance of a JSF 2.1 + PrimeFaces 4.0 webapp with [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/), it recommends among others to defer parsing of JavaScript files. On a test page with a `<p:layout>` and a form with `<p:watermark>` and `<p:fileUpload>` which looks like follows ...

```
<p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100">Test</p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p:inputText id="input" />
            <p:watermark for="input" value="watermark" />
            <p:focus for="input" />
            <p:fileUpload/>
            <p:commandButton value="submit" />
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

... it lists the following JavaScript files which could be deferred:

- `primefaces.js` (219.5KiB)
- `jquery-plugins.js` (191.8KiB)
- `jquery.js` (95.3KiB)
- `layout.js` (76.4KiB)
- `fileupload.js` (23.8KiB)
- `watermark.js` (4.7KiB)

It links to [this Google Developers article](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#DeferLoadingJS) wherein deferred loading is explained as well as how to achieve it. You basically need to dynamically create the desired `<script>` during the `onload` event of the `window`. At its simplest form whereby old and buggy browsers are completely ignored, it looks like this:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "filename.js";
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
</script>
```

Okay, this is doable if you have control over those scripts, but the listed scripts are all forcibly auto-included by JSF. Also, PrimeFaces renders a bunch of inline scripts to HTML output which are directly calling `$(xxx)` from `jquery.js` and `PrimeFaces.xxx()` from `primefaces.js`. This would mean that it would not easily be possible to really defer them to `onload` event as you would only end up with errors like `$ is undefined` and `PrimeFaces is undefined`.

But, it should be technically possible. Given that only jQuery doesn't need to be deferred as many of the site's custom scripts also rely on it, how could I block JSF from forcibly auto-including the PrimeFaces scripts so that I can defer them, and how could I deal with those inline `PrimeFaces.xxx()` calls?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Use `<o:deferredScript>`

Yes, it is possible with the `<o:deferredScript>` component which is new since [OmniFaces](https://omnifaces.org) 1.8.1. For the technically interested, here's the involved source code:

- The UI component: [`DeferredScript`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/4.x/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/component/script/DeferredScript.java)
- The HTML renderer: [`DeferredScriptRenderer`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/4.x/src/main/java/org/omnifaces/renderer/DeferredScriptRenderer.java)
- The JS helper: [`deferred.unminified.js`](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/4.x/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/omnifaces/omnifaces.js/DeferredScript.ts)

Basically, the component will during the `postAddToView` event (thus, during the view build time) via [`UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewroot#addComponentResource(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext,jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent,java.lang.String)) add itself as a new script resource in end of `<body>`.

The renderer will write a `<script>` element with `OmniFaces.DeferredScript.add()` whereby the JSF-generated resource URL is passed. This JS helper will in turn collect the resource URLs and dynamically create new `<script>` elements for each of them during the `onload` event.

The usage is fairly simple, just use `<o:deferredScript>` the same way as `<h:outputScript>`, with a `library` and `name`. It doesn't matter where you place the component, but most self-documenting would be in the *end* of the `<h:head>` like this:

```xml
<h:head>
    ...
    <o:deferredScript library="libraryname" name="resourcename.js" />
</h:head>
```

You can have multiple of them and they will ultimately be loaded in the same order as they're declared.

---

### How to use `<o:deferredScript>` with PrimeFaces?

This is a little tricky, indeed because of all those inline scripts generated by PrimeFaces, but still doable with a helper script and accepting that its `jquery.js` won't be deferred (it *can* however be served via a CDN, see later). In order to cover those inline `PrimeFaces.xxx()` calls to its `components.js` file which is almost 500KiB large in PrimeFaces 13, a helper script needs to be created which is less than 0.5KiB [minified](https://jscompress.com/):

```js
DeferredPrimeFaces = function() {
    var deferredPrimeFaces = {};
    var calls = [];
    var settings = {};
    var primeFacesLoaded = !!window.PrimeFaces;

    function defer(name, args) {
        calls.push({ name: name, args: args });
    }
    
    deferredPrimeFaces.begin = function() {
        if (!primeFacesLoaded) {
            settings = window.PrimeFaces.settings;
            delete window.PrimeFaces;
        }
    };

    deferredPrimeFaces.apply = function() {
        if (window.PrimeFaces) {
            window.PrimeFaces.settings = settings;

            for (var i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
                window.PrimeFaces[calls[i].name].apply(window.PrimeFaces, calls[i].args);
            }
        }

        delete window.DeferredPrimeFaces;
    };

    if (!primeFacesLoaded) {
        window.PrimeFaces = {
            ab: function() { defer("ab", arguments); },
            cw: function() { defer("cw", arguments); },
            focus: function() { defer("focus", arguments); },
            settings: {}
        };
    }

    return deferredPrimeFaces;
}();
```

Save it as `/resources/yourapp/scripts/primefaces.deferred.js`. Basically, all what it does is capturing the `PrimeFaces.ab()`, `cw()` and `focus()` calls (as you can find in the bottom of the script) and deferring them to the `DeferredPrimeFaces.apply()` call (as you can find halfway the script). Note that there are possibly more `PrimeFaces.xxx()` functions which need to be deferred, if that is the case in your app, then you can add them yourself inside `window.PrimeFaces = {}` (no, it's in JavaScript not possible to have a "catch-all" method to cover the undetermined functions).

Before using this script and `<o:deferredScript>`, we first need to determine the auto-included scripts in the generated HTML output. For a test page using PrimeFaces 13 `<p:inputText>`, `<p:fileUpload>` and `<p:commandButton>`, the following scripts are auto-included in generated HTML `<head>` (you can find this by rightclicking the page in webbrowser and choosing *View Source*):

```xml
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/jakarta.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=13.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/jakarta.faces.resource/core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=13.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/jakarta.faces.resource/components.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=13.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/jakarta.faces.resource/jquery/jquery-plugins.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=13.0.0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/jakarta.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=13.0.0"></script>
```

You need to skip the `jquery.js` file and create `<o:deferredScripts>` in exactly the same order for the remaining scripts. The resource name is the part after `/jakarta.faces.resource/` *excluding* the JSF mapping (`.xhtml` in my case). The library name is represented by `ln` request parameter.

Thus, this should do:

```xml
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript library="yourapp" name="scripts/primefaces.deferred.js" target="head" />
    <o:deferredScript library="primefaces" name="core.js" onbegin="DeferredPrimeFaces.begin()" />
    <o:deferredScript library="primefaces" name="components.js" />
    <o:deferredScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" />
    <o:deferredScript library="primefaces" name="fileupload/fileupload.js" onsuccess="DeferredPrimeFaces.apply()" />
</h:head>
```

Now all those scripts with a total size of almost 750KiB in PrimeFaces 13 are deferred to `onload` event. Note that `DeferredPrimeFaces.begin()` must be called in `onbegin` of the **first** `<o:deferredScript library="primefaces" ...>` and that `DeferredPrimeFaces.apply()` must be called in `onsuccess` of the **last** `<o:deferredScript library="primefaces" ...>`.

As to performance improvement, important measuring point is the `DOMContentLoaded` time as you can find in bottom of *Network* tab of Chrome's developer tools. With the test page as shown in your question served by Tomcat on a 3 year old laptop, it decreased from ~500ms to ~270ms. This is relatively huge (almost the half!) and makes the most difference on mobiles/tablets as they render HTML relatively slow and touch events are fully blocked until the DOM content is loaded.

**Warning:** if you're adding new PrimeFaces components on the same view afterwards and are facing JavaScript `undefined` errors, then the chance is big that the new component also comes with its own JS file which should also be deferred, because it's depending on `primefaces.js`. A quick way to figure the right script would be to check the generated HTML `<head>` for the new script and then add another `<o:deferredScript>` for it based on the above instructions.

---

### Bonus: `CombinedResourceHandler` recognizes `<o:deferredScript>`

If you happen to use OmniFaces [`CombinedResourceHandler`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler), then it's good to know that it transparently recognizes `<o:deferredScript>` and combines all deferred scripts with the same `group` attribute into a single deferred resource. E.g. this ...

```xml
<o:deferredScript group="essential" ... />
<o:deferredScript group="essential" ... />
<o:deferredScript group="essential" ... />
...
<o:deferredScript group="non-essential" ... />
<o:deferredScript group="non-essential" ... />
```

... will end up in two combined deferred scripts which are loaded synchronously after each other. Note: the `group` attribute is optional. If you don't have any, then they will just all be combined into a single deferred resource.

---

### Bonus #2: delegate PrimeFaces jQuery to CDN

In any case, if you're already using OmniFaces, then you can always use [`CDNResourceHandler`](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler) to delegate the PrimeFaces jQuery resource to a true CDN by the following context param in `web.xml`:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
    <param-value>primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This can possibly yet further improve performance if the user has beforehand already visited another website which also uses the very same jQuery from CDN.

Comment: Very nice feature and usefull explanation. Thank you. Can resources retrieved via `CDNResourceHandler` also be marked for deferred loading? in `web.xml`?

Comment: Bonus #2: The following configuration is not version dependent and works for Primefaces 13.0.1.

<context-param>
  <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
  <param-value>jquery-cdn:*=https://code.jquery.com/*</param-value>
 </context-param>

Source: https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CDNResourceHandler

Answer (score 4):

Initially posted as an answer to [Defer primefaces.js loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813709/defer-primefaces-js-loading/29403270#29403270)

---

Adding another solution to this question for anyone else that encounters the same.

You will need to customize the primefaces `HeadRenderer` to achieve the ordering pagespeed recommends. While this is something that could have been implemented by PrimeFaces, I do not see it in v5.2.RC2. These are the lines in `encodeBegin` that need change:

```
96         //Registered Resources
97         UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();
98         for (UIComponent resource : viewRoot.getComponentResources(context, "head")) {
99             resource.encodeAll(context);
100        }
```

Simply write a custom component for the `head` tag, then bind it to a renderer that overrides above behavior.

Now you wouldn't want to duplicate the entire method just for this change, it may be cleaner to add a facet called "last" and move script resources to its beginning in your renderer as new `deferredScript` components. Let me know if there's interest, and I'll create a fork to demonstrate how.

This approach is "future proof" in the sense that it doesn't break as new resource dependencies are added to components, or as new components are added to the view.

Comment: This doesn't defer loading of PrimeFaces JS files. Reordering != Deferring. The question contains an example JS code snippet which achieves true deferred loading.

Comment: @BalusC: It actually does. I'm achieving the reordering in the `head` component and delegating deferring to the `deferredScript` component.

Comment: No problem. [Here's](https://github.com/thazarik/omnifaces/commit/71f0bf072a9d74a144d71770e70c44fb5f7d74fa#diff-ef9e51241f47affca1d49aea4ba96cad) an example using omnifaces.

Comment: Oh, now I finally understand you! It wasn't directly clear from the answer that you would replace them by OmniFaces `DeferredScript` components. You might want to clarify that in the answer, along with the relevant code snippet. That's after all indeed also a nice approach. It only doesn't work well with `CombinedResourceHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a minor bug in the js script when it comes to primefaces 12.

window.PrimeFaces.settings = settings;

must be set BEFORE the apply loop (Otherwise, e.g. the paginator of a dataview does not work and you get a runtime error)

The primefaces.deferred.js file:

```
DeferredPrimeFaces = function() {

var deferredPrimeFaces = {};
var calls = [];
var settings = {};
var primeFacesLoaded = !!window.PrimeFaces;

function defer(name, args) {
    calls.push({ name: name, args: args });
}


deferredPrimeFaces.begin = function() {
    if (!primeFacesLoaded) {
        
        settings = window.PrimeFaces.settings;
        
        delete window.PrimeFaces;
    }
};

deferredPrimeFaces.apply = function() {
window.PrimeFaces.settings = settings;

    if (window.PrimeFaces) {
        for (var i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
            window.PrimeFaces[calls[i].name].apply(window.PrimeFaces, calls[i].args);
        }

    
    }

    delete window.DeferredPrimeFaces;
};

if (!primeFacesLoaded) {
    window.PrimeFaces = {
        ab: function() { defer("ab", arguments); },
        cw: function() { defer("cw", arguments); },
        focus: function() { defer("focus", arguments); },
        settings: {
        }
    };
}

return deferredPrimeFaces;  }();
```

And here is an example for the xhtml file within the head section:
Don't forget onbegin and onsuccess attributes for the first and last deferred script:

```
    <h:outputScript name="javascript/primefaces.deferred.js"
    target="head" />

<o:deferredScript group="essential" library="primefaces"
    name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" />
    
<o:deferredScript group="essential" library="primefaces" name="core.js" 
    onbegin="DeferredPrimeFaces.begin()" />

<o:deferredScript group="essential" library="primefaces"
    name="components.js" />
```

```
<o:deferredScript group="mygroup"
    name="javascript/myscripts" target="head" onsuccess="DeferredPrimeFaces.apply()" />
```