# Autoplay of carousel stops working when PrimeFaces JS are deferred

Tags: jsf, primefaces, carousel, omnifaces, combinedresourcehandler

The carousel is showing up but is not autoplaying, here is the code `<p:carousel autoPlayInterval="4000" effectDuration="2000" effect="fade" circular="true" var="var" value="#{mybean.topratedList}" numVisible="1" responsive="true" >` 
When I switch off the `CombinedResourceHandler` the carousel works again fine. 
I'm using primefaces 5.3.7 and Omnifaces 2.4 
Thanks in advance

**Update**:
This problem vanishes when I stop delegating PrimeFaces jQuery to CDN with Omnifaces like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173639/defer-loading-and-parsing-of-primefaces-javascript-files) - removing from web.xml this code snippet 
`<context-param>
        <param-name>org.omnifaces.CDN_RESOURCE_HANDLER_URLS</param-name>
        <param-value>primefaces:jquery/jquery.js=http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.4.min.js</param-value>
    </context-param>`

Comment: You mean, you are using `<o:deferredScript>`? Have you carefully followed the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/q/23173639? In the case the carousel doesn't work, are you seeing any errors in JS console? That would be indicative that scripts responsible for `<p:carousel>` are not properly deferred.

Comment: Just updated my text above. In fact, I see an error in the console ´Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(…)´ which vanishes when I remove CDN. Strange because other components like Gmap and  selectManyCheckbox were working fine.

Comment: Yes I'm using `<o:deferredScript>` and Omnifaces for long time and it is working properly.